# Typescript static methods inheritance

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm working on an ionic 2 project using typescript 2.0.6.

I have a Base class which manage some behaviors and I inherit several classes from this base class. 
And I want to be able to get the name of the actual class (not the base one).

Here is my code :

```
export class AbstractModel {
    oneInstanceMethod() {
        this.getClassName();
    }
    static oneStaticMethod() {
        this.getClassName();
    }
    getClassName() {
        return (<any>this).constructor.name;
    }
    static getClassName() {
        return (<any>this).name;
    }
}

export class MyClass1 extends AbstractModel {

}
export class MyClass2 extends AbstractModel {

}
```

And I have 2 kind of calls : Either `MyClass1.oneStaticMethod()` or `(new MyClass2).oneInstanceMethod()`.

My problem is that this code was working before (now I get 'e' because it returns the function e()) I made some upgrade in my ionic project. I think my typescript version has been upgraded (i'm not sure but I think it was the 1.8 before).

How can I solve this ? I tried many things (like creating variables to store the values, but neither works in static mode AND instance mode).

Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like your code is being minified. The code you've posted [seems to work as intended](https://jsfiddle.net/7bp44voz/)?

Comment: You can typically tweak the minification class to keep class and function names as they are, though you might need to rethink your design (i.e. *why* would you need a class name? or is it for debugging?)

Comment: no i'm writing an ORM and I want to abstract a lot of things in the Base class. And I want to use the class name as my SQL table name.

Comment: the thing is I don't care if I need to declare the table name in the inherited classes, but it seems that if it executes a static method which is located in the base class, it call properties and methods from itself and not the MyClass1 or MyClass2 prop or methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I copy your code ad verbatim and add:

```
var a = new MyClass1();
var b = new MyClass2();

document.body.innerHTML = a.getClassName() + " - " + b.getClassName();
```

Then [it runs as you expect](https://jsfiddle.net/7bp44voz/).

**The issue you're experiencing is most likely due to minification.** Your class names get garbled in minification. Most minifiers have an option to disable renaming of classes/functions, you haven't mentioned which one you use but surely their docs say something about this. It will increase file size though.

You clarified a bit in comments, and I'd still recommend not using class names, but prefer being explicit about this kind of thing. With Typescript you *gain* tooling support for automated renames, but you kinda throw that away again. Then again, that's your own design decision to make.

---

Footnote: here's a solution that might be useful or not, depending on your design preferences. It dispatches the knowledge on associated table name to an instance variable:

```
class AbstractModel {
  _tableName: string = null;

  getClassName = () => {
    if (!this._tableName) {
      throw new Error("No table name was set for this DTO.");
    }
    return this._tableName;
  }
}

class MyClass1 extends AbstractModel {
    _tableName = "MyTable1";
}

class MyClass2 extends AbstractModel {
    _tableName = "AnotherTable2";
}

var a = new MyClass1();
var b = new MyClass2();

document.body.innerHTML = a.getClassName() + " - " + b.getClassName();
```

See it [in action on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bp44voz/1/).

Note that I also snuck in this:

```
getClassName = () => {
```

vs

```
getClassName() {
```

So that `this` is correctly captured and refers to the class instance, not the function that's executing.

Comment: thank you ! i'm trying to find the minifier, but I understand that it's better to be explicit but I can't have typescript use my inherited static methods or property from the base class. It always calls the base class method or property, so I can't really override my variables. At this point, using the class name was the only working solution :(

Comment: I've added a possible way to solve this problem, see the footnote. (Beware that to get `this` to work properly in member methods, it can be convenient to create them as lambda's, not as regular `function`s.)

Comment: thanks ! let me try because I always have pb with static methods

Comment: ok it works when I use the same strategy with static members, but I need to call the member directly (not via a static method otherwise it won't take the inherited value of the static member).